# Is there a formula that takes the adjacent cell to the top 10 values and deals with identical values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, presentation

In order to better analyse pages over time for **SEO optimisations** and rankings, I've made an excel spreadsheet that pulls in the top 20 pages by impressions and compares it to the top 20 pages by clicks.

I download the report for pages from **Google Search Console** and copy it into a sheet called **PageDataInput**. In a sheet called **Page** it pulls the top 20 pages according to the key metric chosen, either impressions or clicks

The table for impressions works without issue because there aren't any duplicate impressions and there is a low likelihood that there will be. However, this isn't the same with clicks.

Instead of referencing the next page with the same value, it just references the same page with that click for as long as there are duplicate values. Meaning that if there are 5 pages with the same click value, it'll reference the first page 5 times and then move on to the next page.

For Impressions I've used:

```
=INDEX(PageDataInput!$B$2:$B$952,MATCH(1,INDEX((PageDataInput!$D$2:$D$952=LARGE(PageDataInput!$D$2:$D$952,ROWS(B$2:B2)))*(COUNTIFS(B$2:B2,PageDataInput!$D$2:$D$952)=0),),0))
```

For Clicks I used the same code just different column to check:

```
=INDEX(PageDataInput!$B$2:$B$952,MATCH(1,INDEX((PageDataInput!$C$2:$C$952=LARGE(PageDataInput!$C$2:$C$952,ROWS(I$2:I2)))*(COUNTIFS(I$2:I2,PageDataInput!$C$2:$C$952)=0),),0))
```

The columns are all set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deal with duplicates with respect to the amount of clicks you can create a new column which adds an incremental amount to the number of clicks and reference this column instead.

The easiest way to do this is by adding a very small random number:

```
+RAND()/100000
```

This will not really change the results but the LARGE function will work fine as the numbers are now essentially distinct.

Comment: great this worked! I was hoping for something that didn't require a helper column, but this seems to work nicely so cheers.